# Access 2003 Chart X-Axis is truncated

Tags: ms-access, charts

I was wondering if someone can give me some insight into a problem I am having. I am using Microsoft Access 2003 and developing charts. The problem is with the X-Axis (Vertical) Title. It seems it is being truncated it some instances but not others. When I work on one monitor it works fine; but on another one it does not. It seems to be a monitor problem not a printer problem because the printed copy is roughly the same as what I see on the screen.

Access won’t let me increase the length of the box; shortening the text, which I don’t want to do anyway does not seem to help.

I’ve seen this problem described for Excel chart but not Access.

Thanks in advance.